# Finding numbers within an area of 10 in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I'm currently programming a Web game for my APCS end-of-year project. I'm trying to find the closest number in an array that is full of coords for towns. Since it is coords, I need to do this for an X and Y array. For example, x=[10, 20, 30], y=[20, 10, 23], the first town would be at [10, 20]. But since exactly finding this exact location would be hard, there is a area of 10 coords around it that you can be in, in order to discover the town.

Here's my current code:

```
function setTowns() {
  for(i = 0; i < 9000; i++){
    townLocations.x.push(random(-1000, 1000));
    townLocations.y.push(random(-1000, 1000));
  }
}

function checkTown() {
  var townX = townLocations.x;
  var townY = townLocations.y;

  for(i = 0; i < townX.length; i++){
    if((Math.abs(townX[i]) - Math.abs(bb.location.x)) < 10){
      console.log(townX[i]);
      for(i = 0; i < townY.length; i++){
        if((Math.abs(townY[i]) - Math.abs(bb.location.y)) < 10){
          console.log(townY[i]);
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

checkTown() is called every time the player moves.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the question. Also how do `x=[10, 20, 30], y=[20, 10, 23]` considered as coordinates? is it a 3-d array? what's the meaning of `[10,20] in that case?

Comment: Going way off track using different arrays for x and y coords. Create objects with coords. Also time to break out the math text books. Simple `x-x` and `y-y` isn't going to do much for 2d distance calcs. Beyond that....what is your question?

Comment: @charlietfl The coords are stored within an object, the townLocations object which has an x and y array property. My game is built off a coord system, as you have to control a robot through a command prompt. When the robot is instructed to move, I need to have it calculate if the robot's coords are near a town's coords.

Comment: `var towns = [{name:'foo', x:2,  y:3},{name:'bar', x:7,  y:1}]` .. make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Imaging a map looking like this:

1 0 0 0 0 0
0 **0** **1** **0** 0 1
0 **0** ‍♀️**0** 0 0
0 **1** **0** **0** 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0

Ones are a town, and zeros contains nothing. ‍♀️ marks the player.

You can use *Pythagorean theorem* to spot any kind of "collision". Let say the player is close to two towns (the ones) and each town has it's own coordinate (X, Y), as well as the player. Draw a triangle in your mind, where the Y coordinates for both places creates one side of the triangle, and the X coordinates are another side. The distance is the hypotenuse.

Let say that the distance for collision (read: detection) is 1. If the player is on coordinate (3, 3), would a town with coordinate (2, 4) be close enough? One side of the triangle would go from 3 to 2 and the other from 3 to 4. What's the hypotenuse, aka the distance?

OK, that's math for children, because you can probably see it straight away, but lets see the math behind it.

```
let playerXCoordinate = 3;
let playerYCoordinate = 3;

let townXCoordinate = 2;
let townYCoordinate = 4;

let xDifference = playerXCoordinate - townXCoordinate; // 3 - 2
let yDifference = playerYCoordinate - townYCoordinate; // 3 - 4

    // Pythagorean theorem
let hypotenuseAsDistance = Math.sqr( Math.pow(xDifference, 2) + Math.pow(yDifference, 2))
// √(1^2 + 1^2) = √1 = 1

let isWithinDistance = hypotenuseAsDistance <= 1 // true
```

Lets take another example. This time with a town located at (5, 4).

```
let xDifference = 3 - 5;
let yDifference = 3 - 4

let hypotenuseAsDistance = Math.sqr( Math.pow(xDifference, 2) + Math.pow(yDifference, 2))
// √((3-5)^2 + (3-4)^2) = √(2^2+1^2) = √(4+1) = √5 = 2.23606797749979

let isWithinDistance = hypotenuseAsDistance <= 1 // false
```

A shorter version is, however, available as part of the Math object.

```
let xDifference = 3 - 5;
let yDifference = 3 - 4;

let hypotenuseAsDistance = Math.hypot(xDifference, yDifference);
```

---

So as for your example, it would be something like this.

```
let playerXPos = 3; // just an example
let playerXPos = 4; // just an example

let townArrLength = townLocations.x;
let detectionRange = 10;

let townXPos = 0;
let townYPos = 0;
let distance = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < townArrLength; i++) {
  townXPos = townLocations.x[i];
  townYPos = townLocations.y[i];
  distance = Math.hypot(playerXPos - townXPos, playerYPos - townYPos);

  if (distance <= detectionRange) {
     // do something
  }
}
```

---

*For more reading:*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection